# Does Mulesoft automatically handle CDC gap and overflow events?

Tags: change-data-capture, mulesoft, replication

**Does Mulesoft automagically handles Salesforce Change Data Capture (CDC) Gap and Overflow events automagically?**

It would be nice it that was the case, rather than have to engineer some solution to query back to the Salesforce database and pull the rows in the gap event as per the handling patterns described in the SF CDC Guide:

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.change_data_capture.meta/change_data_capture/cdc_replication_steps.htm

I could not find any Mulesoft documentation on it, and not sure how to get a Mulesoft development environment to just try it out myself.

Anyone have any experience with using CDC and Mulesoft for table replication?

Comment: It has a simple replay option. https://docs.mulesoft.com/salesforce-connector/10.12/salesforce-connector-processing-events#channelrep